# Fake jQuery mouse events in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, phantomjs

I'm [writing some tests](https://github.com/simonsmith/jquery.herotabs/blob/jasmine-headless/tests/jquery.herotabs-spec.js#L349) with Jasmine to run in PhantomJS. One test uses the `$.Event` constructor to trigger a fake mouse event. Example:

```
$('.elem').trigger($.Event('click', {
    target: $('.elem').find('.a-child')[0]
}));
```

This works fine in Chrome, Firefox etc but fails to fire in PhantomJS. The same happens with `mouseenter`. Interestingly it works fine in PhantomJS if I do key events, it just seems to be the mouse.

Is there a way round this, or a better way to fake the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems PhantomJS uses touch events instead of click, which explains the failure. `Modernizr.touch` returns true in PhantomJS

[I ended up](https://github.com/simonsmith/jquery.herotabs/blob/master/tests/jquery.herotabs-spec.js#L349) attaching to either touch or click depending on the result of a test:

```
nav.trigger($.Event(Modernizr.touch ? 'touchstart' : 'click', {
    target: nav.find('a').get(1)
}));
```

Sadly this doesn't help with `mouseenter` or `mouseleave` events. Closest detail I could find was [this old bug report](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10375).